# Does each indention option override the previous one?

Tags: vimrc, indentation, options

From `:h indent.txt`:

> ...each one overrides the previous if it is enabled...

Now if I set `'cin'` after `'ai'`, Does `'cin'` disable the effect of `'ai'`?.
*If no, so what is the purpose of "override" exactly?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order does not matter.  The override behavior is based on what is currently set/unset, changing one option value does not change others.  Additionally, `indent.txt` refers to *methods* not *settings*, so the behavior is not completely straight-forward since the expression in `indentexpr` can itself return "not enabled."  The documentation requires some further explanation:

1. If `indentexpr` is set, `cindent`,`smartindent`, and `autoindent` will all have no base effect (* caveat 1 applies).  Note that for `indentexpr` "unset" means set to empty string.
2. If `cindent` is set and `indentexpr` is unset, `{smartindent,autoindent}` will have no effect.
3. If `smartindent` is set and `{cindent, indentexpr}` are unset, `autoindent` 
   will have no effect (* caveat 2 applies).
4. Finally, if `{cindent, indentexpr, smartindent}` are unset `autoindent` takes effect.

(* caveat 1 ) If `indentexpr` returns -1, vim specifies that the value of `autoindent` is used.  So, if `smartindent` or `cindent` is on, and `autoindent` is off, and the `indentexpr` evaluates to -1, indenting will not take place, which is potentially unexpected.

(* caveat 2 ) The documentation is misleading here.  You *should* set `autoindent` if you have `smartindent` for reasons that are unclear (besides perhaps the reason given in (* caveat 1) above).  From `:h smartindent`:

```
Normally 'autoindent' should also be on when using 'smartindent'.
```

The bottom line is you should always set "lesser" indent methods when using "greater" ones, although it sometimes doesn't matter.